# Why Javascript window.open('a url ') returns null in firefox js console?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to open a new window or a new tab through Firefox JavaScript console.
when I type

```
window.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

it returns **null** !
any ideas?

Comment: What would you expect it to return?

Comment: where you type ?

Comment: @Pavlo I expect a new window to be opened!

Comment: @rahul_m I type in fire fox inspector / console

Comment: Working fine for me. Can you tell us how are you checking the existence of value?

Comment: @Rajesh What do you mean ? Do you Think it might be because of firefox preferences ?

Comment: which firefox version you are using, its seriously working here, check in your setting, if you blocked popup in your browser

Comment: @AfsaneFadaei You said it returns `null`. So I'm assuming you must have done something like: `variable = window.open(...)` right? then how are you checking value of this `variable`

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you very much. it was my Firefox preferences fault.Thank you :)

Comment: @rahul_m Thank you very much. it was my Firefox preferences fault.Thank you :)

Comment: For reference: I believe the problem was that Firefox was set in the preferences to block pop-ups (i.e., window.open('https://address.com', **'_blank'**)). The warning by the URL address bar about a pop-up window being blocked is very discreet and easy to miss

Answer (score -1):

```
window.open('http://stackoverflow.com',300,300);
```

Just try with above code.Hope this will helps.
Here i had provide width and height for new window.

Comment: Why would it help? Please explain what and **why** have you changed

Comment: @Rajesh as didn't mention that height/width it will open `url` in new tab, i think and i tried same.

Comment: By passing height and width, you are setting dimensions of newly opened window. But irrespective to values, it will open a window and would return its reference. So your answer will not help'

Comment: It didn't open window,it will open new tab.And question is about to open new window.

Comment: Thats not the question. Question is OP was getting return value as `null` but it should be reference of window.

Comment: Also as OP has commented, issue was with browser's preference and hence this will not help. Please delete your answer

Answer (score -1):

The above expression will return null in any console anyway, because you're just calling a function, you're not typing a variable or other expression. In my Firefox it **does** try to open a new window, but I get a pop-up warning instead (which is normal, I either set this as default in Firefox or I installed an extension that blocks pop-ups).

Comment: Please read comments under question. OP has stated that issue was with browser's preference.

Comment: OP doesn't mention what exactly in her preferences was causing this behaviour, and in any case, I also get null in my Firefox console and I consider this normal, because as I wrote above, I did not assign the return value of the function to any variable to be evaluated by the console.

Comment: @Rajesh maybe you should go easy on the down-voting, we're all trying to help here.

Comment: First, *expression will return null in any console anyway* is wrong. Try `console.log(window.open(...))`. Second, if the real issue was that OP is not assigning variable, that should have been a typographical mistake and should have been closed but not answered. So either way, your answer will not help. Also as this is not a programmatic problem, this does not belong on SO, but OP will not be able to delete due to answers. So I would request you to delete your answer. Any rep you have lost will return on deletion